# ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form with a `submit` button, but I keep getting an error:

> submitForm is not defined.

```
<form action="/action.php" method="GET">
    <label for="Name">Name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:
        <input type="email" name="user-email" id="email">
    </label>
    <input id="contactSubmit" type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="Submit">
    <script src="contact-us.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

"submitForm" in your message is a name of the function. It's called when someone is clicking on the button (click event; "onclick" in your input tag). The message tells that this function in not defined. Make sure that you defined it earlier in you JS-code.